# How to get list of all manager using hierarchical query

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-query

I would like to pull list of employees who are managers of me.
Have a look at below query:

```
SELECT   SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (username, ':') AS "Liste Membres",LEVEL
  FROM   employees
 WHERE   CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
         AND username = '150') -- My_code
START WITH   manager IS NULL
CONNECT BY   PRIOR username = manager
```

The result of this query is:

```
:1:20:120:150
```

The result that I want to get:

```
:1:20:120:
```

Comment: can you show me please the data in the table ?

Comment: Why don't you just strip youe username of? `SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (username, ':'), 1, LENGTH(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (username, ':'))-LENGTH(username))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (manager, ':')` and then remove the leading `:` that is appended for the root level `NULL` manager (and if you want the trailing `:` then add `|| ':'`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8c17/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES ( manager, username ) AS
  SELECT NULL, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 120, 150 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (manager, ':'), 2 ) AS "Liste Membres",
         LEVEL
FROM     employees
WHERE    CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
AND      username = '150' -- My_code
START WITH   manager IS NULL
CONNECT BY   PRIOR username = manager
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8c17/5/0)**:

```
| Liste Membres | LEVEL |
|---------------|-------|
|     :1:20:120 |     4 |
```